# Why is this apt install chrome failing?

Tags: apt, chrome

What could be the problem here?

```
apt install -y google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Sub-process Popen returned an error code (2)
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.  Use `dpkg` for local deb files.  `apt` is for downloading files from a repository.

Comment: `apt` should and must be used to install deb packages or otherwise you risk breaking your deb database. To the OP, does `sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` work?

Comment: `dpkg` doesn't check dependencies before installing a package, I've had a situtation multiple times when I installed packages directly using `dpkg` and then had to recover the DPKG database as installing/updating/removing packages using no less than `apt` led to errors.

Comment: After a few more tries it worked without errors. Not sure what the problem was.